# antlr4 How to fix lexer mode implicit token error?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a token collision with some text and was thinking about using lexer modes to work around the issues.

I create the mode in the Lexer file, but when I complie the Parser file I get the following warnings:

```
warning(125): TSqlParser.g4:2377:26: implicit definition of token DISK in parser
warning(125): TSqlParser.g4:2377:31: implicit definition of token TAPE in parser
warning(125): TSqlParser.g4:2377:36: implicit definition of token URL in parser
```

How can I fix this?

My mode definition are:

```
BACKUP:                                'BACKUP' -> pushMode(BackupTokens);

mode BackupTokens:
DISK:                                  'DISK' -> popMode();
TAPE:                                  'TAPE' -> popMode();
URL:                                   'URL' -> popMode();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your lexer grammar:

- it's not `popMode()` but `popMode`
- it's not `mode BackupTokens:` but `mode BackupTokens;`

So, when you lexer grammar is called `TSqlLexer` with the following contents:

```antlr
lexer grammar TSqlLexer;

BACKUP : 'BACKUP' -> pushMode(BackupTokens);

mode BackupTokens;
  DISK : 'DISK' -> popMode;
  TAPE : 'TAPE' -> popMode;
  URL  : 'URL'  -> popMode;
```

Then your parser grammar should include the proper `tokenVocab` in its `options { ... }` block:

```antlr
parser grammar TSqlParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=TSqlLexer;
}

...
```

### EDIT

> Do you know where the mode block stops? Or does it run to EOF ?

The mode blocks stops at the `EOF`, or at the next `mode`.

Tip: define `fragment`s in the top-most part of your grammar so that you can use these `fragment`s from all of your modes:

```antlr
lexer grammar TSqlLexer;

BACKUP : 'BACKUP' -> pushMode(BackupTokens);

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];

mode BackupTokens;
  ...
  A_RULE: DIGIT;

mode OtherMode;
  ...
  SOME_RULE: DIGIT+;
```

Comment: Thanks. I lifted the syntax from a blog page. :|  Do you know where the mode block stops? Or does it run to EOF ?

Comment: @garyM check my **EDIT**

Comment: Absolutely awesome.  This is some of the clearest doc I've found.